# I have to make this table in html

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am taking coaching for html again and have been told to make this html table inside another table its very tough for me:

[image]

I have tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>table within a table</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylehomework.css">
</head>
<body>
<table height="60px" border="3" div class="homework">
<h1>This is first class for class homework 22 january</h1>
    <thead>
        <th >first row</th>
        <th>second row</th>
        <th>third row</th>

    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <tr>

    <td height="60px">first column</td>
    <tr>
    <td>second row</td>
    <td>third  row</td>

    </tr>
    <tr border="3" >
        <td height="70px">second column</td>
        <td>second column</td>
        <td>Second </td>
    </tr
    <tr>
    <td height="80px">Thid column</td>
    <td>third</td>
    <td>third</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am a beginner in html/css:

[image]

Comment: In the image, the first row is very unclear to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a table which look like.
basic idea is to insert table in cell.
Check for your requirement, little modification can help you to learn

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:100%" border="3" >
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>
    <table style="width:100%" border="3" >
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>
    
    <table style="width:100%" border="3" >
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    
    </td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```